# How do you use regex to split numbered list

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to split a large number of strings in the following format into a list of dictionaries in python

> 1) Qianfeigong 钱妃宫 was originally called the Zhenhuimiao 贞惠庙, and later the Qianlinggong 钱灵宫. The temple was built during the Northern Song in Yuanfeng 7 (1083). The temple was renovated during the early Ming. In 1967 the temple was demolished, but it was rebuilt in 1985. The main god is Qianshi shengfei 钱氏圣妃. Secondary gods are Guangping Zhouwang 广平周王 and Taishan Kongwang 泰山孔王. The stone inscription composed in the Xianchun period (1265–1274) by Liu Kezhuang 刘克庄 entitled 协应钱夫人庙记 (Record of the Temple to Lady Qian of Beneficial Assistance) (Epigraphical Materials, 1995:54, No. 48) is about this temple (stele no longer extant). 2) Xinglongshê 兴隆社: The main gods are Zunzhu mingwang 尊主明王 and Houtu furen 后土夫人.

I tried the following, but it broke the string along "48)" too.

> re.split("\d+)", string)
>
> Results:
>   1), 48), 2)

48) should not be a result.

I was thinking about excluding results that follow an openning bracket "(", but I am unsure how to go about that.

Comment: With PyPi regex module, you might use `regex.split(r'(?<!\([^()]*)(?!^)(?=\d+\))', text)`

Comment: Can you please show use the expecting result?

Comment: One more thing: I really recommend to use PyPi regex module for such long text parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(?:^|\.\s)\d+\)(?=\s[A-Z])
```

Explained:

```
(?:^|\.\s)(?#start of line or end of sentence)\d+\)(?#Number followed by bracket)(?=\s[A-Z])(?#whitespace then a captital at the start of the sentence)
```

Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/Fierhb/1

Answer (score 1):

When parsing long strings, PyPi `regex` module proves to provide a much faster and more stable performance.

I suggest installing it with `pip install regex` (or `pip3 install regex`), and run

```
import regex
text="1) Qianfeigong 钱妃宫 was originally called the Zhenhuimiao 贞惠庙, and later the Qianlinggong 钱灵宫. The temple was built during the Northern Song in Yuanfeng 7 (1083). The temple was renovated during the early Ming. In 1967 the temple was demolished, but it was rebuilt in 1985. The main god is Qianshi shengfei 钱氏圣妃. Secondary gods are Guangping Zhouwang 广平周王 and Taishan Kongwang 泰山孔王. The stone inscription composed in the Xianchun period (1265–1274) by Liu Kezhuang 刘克庄 entitled 协应钱夫人庙记 (Record of the Temple to Lady Qian of Beneficial Assistance) (Epigraphical Materials, 1995:54, No. 48) is about this temple (stele no longer extant). 2) Xinglongshê 兴隆社: The main gods are Zunzhu mingwang 尊主明王 and Houtu furen 后土夫人."
print(regex.split(r'(?<!\([^()]*)(?!^)(?=\d+\))', text))
```

See the [Python 3 demo](https://tio.run/##ZVNdS1RBGL73V7x64zm1LK26ukoiBVGhBqUXtZkw7pk954WzM4eZOel2VZgRSdqHFxZSQRKRJCsa5AZ10T8JZ9Vfsb1zVsHoZs7MnPfjeZ73maRuIin6222sJVIZUDzkC12GL5jRnoIPN5GJKsdQihCOX@3YT4t2ewvmmQapMETB4rgOFVp5ACbiUI64iFKsIZNwtPeutfjBNt/kgIkAYma4yoJc0RhFeFr18NE3qpqHafpneC2JedZhLsXYQJAqCs3ybhDAiCsBUy4RBdxJHTraD4FXuFDq9/@robiQ96lxcLYOZ4pQT9IxD9cFFIYHh7L7M3kBr8kYdcSDHOEwgOakXAcUuqxSsdOuxugYygBQZ9R0hECZIiThHL1WY9VufCTp8jDFK1IETNVdvAamOFwlDmHioJUjmc7TAez@L7u/a19@PlxZzqSbZgSFCRgn3llEa7dhd3bs1zWK6IDQRgpOuHRFYWJQCqhImqgm5oTOsbtN0CpRKiDhCgmtV@gbLP55@LrQNzTgw1wdJjCFcf4gSjMMT9ft0rJtPgYuDBo3X/t81TbXnAs2tw6aTRrs0XYDvFvESQUgq1mX6Y6GRsIEC@qZHu7XZS54FSvIYrikNWpDWLgP3pUEQ8WSCMlDMOkcQiE6R@oOF0eKAzmaeR4GSr7Tls1JmoSJaHsyKU8bTh8hISZlyF1kWyYM2aDPJ74idNc6@v0F7NLe8dsnh5s/R/4ZWWcE5VQQa6jhibq28ezg@4/W@sqp/teocQrVlNwE9sWK3XjfkSDf09WVkK2Mlz2bvE5ipH2vN3axe8a7O@v598753lj3LC2jM8H5Gd/vzYF7XL7fbv8F), output:

```
['1) Qianfeigong 钱妃宫 was originally called the Zhenhuimiao 贞惠庙, and later the Qianlinggong 钱灵宫. The temple was built during the Northern Song in Yuanfeng 7 (1083). The temple was renovated during the early Ming. In 1967 the temple was demolished, but it was rebuilt in 1985. The main god is Qianshi shengfei 钱氏圣妃. Secondary gods are Guangping Zhouwang 广平周王 and Taishan Kongwang 泰山孔王. The stone inscription composed in the Xianchun period (1265–1274) by Liu Kezhuang 刘克庄 entitled 协应钱夫人庙记 (Record of the Temple to Lady Qian of Beneficial Assistance) (Epigraphical Materials, 1995:54, No. 48) is about this temple (stele no longer extant). ', '2) Xinglongshê 兴隆社: The main gods are Zunzhu mingwang 尊主明王 and Houtu furen 后土夫人.']
```

**Details**

- `(?<!\([^()]*)` - no `(` and any 0+ chars other than `(` and `)` immediately to the left of the current location are allowed
- `(?!^)` - no string start position allowed at this point
- `(?=\d+\))` - there must be 1+ digits and `)` immediately to the right of the current location.